# postfix main.cf message_size_limit question

Tags: postfix

Postfix continually gives the following fatal error when running:
'mailbox_size_limit is smaller than message_size_limit'
In postfix main.cf my mailbox_size_limit is 1Mbyte well within the specified limit. I can't find the variable message_size_limit.

Answer (score 1):

I set `mailbox_size_limit` to `0` which means "Unlimited" and this solved the problem